# JTextArea text visibility

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jtextarea

In JFrame Form I have  added a jTextArea and added a text into it, while still in design mode. But when I run the form I want the text to be invisible, which is not happening. I checked the properties of the JTextArea but I am not really sure how to change the visiblity of the text..

Comment: post the JtextArea Containing Code please...

Comment: The JTextArea itself does not have any code because I drew it from Swing Controls and palette option in Netbeans for JFrame form, it only has a text written in it as Select * from client.customers(this is a query connecting to a database, but not really necessary for my question)..I want that line to stay active but not be visible when the form is run....

Answer (score 0):

For clearing the `JTextArea` filed you need to set its text as empty.
For this you need to see `JTextArea#setText` as `null` or `""`.Try this code at the execution of your application.
`jTerxtAreaObject.setText("");`

Comment: Thanks...but I actually want the line there to be still active and not cleared as the code I think you gave indicates. I actually want the line to be still there but not visible when the GUI is run..

Comment: Please clear what you are saying.Do you want that When you run the form then text should be inside the text field but not in edited form.It means you want to disable the textfield? Your requirement is so confusing please explain it

Answer (score 0):

Set the color of the text as the same color as the background.